Bluebeam - batch processing multiple PDFs
Scenario:
I have 1000+ PDF engineering drawings.
The majority of the drawings contain somewhere between 5 and 30 sheets. Maybe 5% contain 100+ sheets.
I have a process of preparing the drawings prior to uploading them to a database. The process is as follows:

Delete all existing markups
Delete all existing page labels and bookmarks
Create page labels that are concatenated from several page regions.
Export each sheet in the drawing to its own file.

I am coming up empty on how to do this to a large batch of files (or even more than one) at once.
I have looked through the bluebeam scripting reference and don't see the references in there to get the job done.
I am not familiar with javascript. But again, I looked online and at forum posts about what can be done with javascript and couldn't concluded if it was possible or not.
Does anyone know if the above can be automated?
Thank you

@KJ thank you for the replies. I will post some screenshots after the weekend to better clarify the reasoning behind the procedures of the page labels.
